# Como hacer una animacion en CSS

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo una duda de como hacer 2 animaciones.

La primera animación es cuando apretó en un elemento del nav y me dirige hacia ese elemento de la pagina. Quiero hacer una animación que baje hasta el elemento.

La segunda, es un progressbar. Necesito que cuando se llegue a ver, que se llene hasta tanto porcentaje. Actualmente lo tengo asi:

```
.progressbar {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 13px;
    padding: 3px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.progressbar div {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

<div class="progressbar">
    <div style="width: 55%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para la primera animación te sugiero utilizar este código de JS:

```
(function($) {
"use strict"; // Start of use strict

// Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 71)
      }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
      return false;
    }
  }
});

// Scroll to top button appear
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollDistance = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scrollDistance > 100) {
    $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
  }
});

// Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
$('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});

// Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '#mainNav',
  offset: 80
});

// Collapse Navbar
var navbarCollapse = function() {
  if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
    $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
  } else {
    $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
  }
};
// Collapse now if page is not at top
navbarCollapse();
// Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
$(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);

// Floating label headings for the contact form
$(function() {
  $("body").on("input propertychange", ".floating-label-form-group", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("floating-label-form-group-with-value", !!$(e.target).val());
  }).on("focus", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
    $(this).addClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
  }).on("blur", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
  });
});
```

Y anidar tus links del navbar con la clase:

```
class= "js-scroll-trigger"
```

Te lo comento porque esa animación es la que utilizo en mi página web:

[Sitio de ejemplo](https://francobuccieri.ml/)